# Conky positioning?

Tags: fluxbox, conky

I'm using conky in fluxbox on Arch, and don't like the position of conky on startup. It's pops up in the middle of the screen when I startup.

Is there a way to set the position of conky on the screen at startup? I want it to stick to the top of the screen automatically.

Comment: Conky has [excellent documentation](http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html): what settings have you tried?

Comment: You must share your conky config, otherwise we wouldn't know where's going wrong, at least the part before `TEXT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try a variation of this in your `.conkyrc`:

```
alignment top_left
gap_x 60
gap_y 60
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this option. I got it working with `alignment top_left gap_x 5 gap_y 5`